# Item price with added zeroes without dot in Google Analytics 4 debug

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, enhanced-ecommerce

I am having trouble with Google Analytics and item prices. When I create an order the price in the dataLayer for the item is for example 287.2 but when you chekc in GA4 debugger you get -> price:2872000000.
I don't understand why is it adding the zeroes and where did the dot go?

The value of the order is parsed ok, the revenue is calculated, but for the item revenue it's almost always 0.

Comment: The price multiplication is a bug in the debugger. It does not affect the real data.